# ASP.NET MVC Web API Delete call using jQuery Ajax with data params not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a web api method like below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// DELETE: api/ftpapi/custom/deletefiles
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="items"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpDelete]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteFiles(string[] items)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

In my view I call this method using Ajax:

```
            var values = $('input:checkbox[name=items]:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
            }).get();

            $.ajax({
                url: uri_api + '/custom/deletefiles',
                method: "DELETE",
                data: { items: values }
            }).done(function (data) {
                    location.reload(true);
                })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            })
            .always(function () {
                $('#loader').fadeOut(200);
                $('body').removeClass('loader-in');
            });
```

When I place a breakpoint at the `return Ok();` and test this out, it works. Except the param `string[] items` is always empty.

If I look into the network tab of Google Chrome I can see the items in my form data:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the value of `values`? And set `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: @StephenMuecke view update.

Comment: Also `data: JSON.stringify({ items: values })`

Comment: Now its `null` instead of an empty array

Comment: @StephenMuecke ok now its solved. I have created a new class model with one property called Items of type string[]

Comment: Or you could use `[FromBody]string[] items`

Comment: @StephenMuecke tried that first but with no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `@Stephen Muecke` I first added some changes to my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     url: uri_api + '/custom/deletefiles',
     method: "DELETE",
     data: JSON.stringify({ 'items': values }), // Added Stringify
     contentType: 'application/json' // Added content type
});
```

Ater that I have created a new class model with one property:

```
public class FtpFilesModel
{
    public string[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then the last thing to do is changing the method property to the new created class:

```
[HttpDelete]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult DeleteFiles(FtpFilesModel files)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

And now its working!

Answer (score 3):

> Change to this: 
>   As JSON.stringify turns a Javascript object into JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

```
  $.ajax({
            url: uri_api + '/custom/deletefiles',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            method: "DELETE",
            data: JSON.stringify({ items: values })
        }).done(function (data) {
                location.reload(true);
            })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
        })
        .always(function () {
            $('#loader').fadeOut(200);
            $('body').removeClass('loader-in');
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing `data: { items: values }`, you should do `data: JSON.stringify({ 'items': values })`.

This is how ajax works with arrays.